# MySQL query in a PHP while loop returns NULL after first result

Tags: php, mysql

I have some mysql tables (one for each container) like so (the table would be called containerA for instance):

```
Box_ID   Box_Name   Box_Distributor   Container     Box_state
======---========---===============---==========----=========
1        Box 1      Delivery Comp.1   ContainerA    Full 
2        Box 2      Delivery Comp.2   ContainerA    Empty
3        Box 3      NULL              ContainerA    Missing
```

and I have another mysql table with a list of containers:

```
container_id   container_name
============---==============
1              A
2              B
```

and I want to report the name of the container and the number of empty boxes to a webpage.

I've written this to do it:

```
    $v1 = 0;
    $sql = "select * from containers";
    $result = mysql_query ($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
    { 
        $containers[] = $row[container_name];
        $containerid[] = $row[container_id];

    }

    while ($v1 < 14)
    {

        $containerend = $containers[$v1];
        $containerstart = "container";
        $containername = $containerstart.$containerend;

        $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `$containername` WHERE state = 'Empty';";
        $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
        $count = mysql_fetch_array($result);
        var_dump($containers[$v1]);
        var_dump($count[$v1]);
        $v2 = $v1 + 1;
        $v1 = $v2;

    }
```

Which works in listing the container names, but it only gives me the first result for the empty boxes, the rest of the array is returned as NULL:

```
string(1) "4" NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL
```

Am I doing something stupid here? Surely the SQL query in the while loop should be returning the count for each container?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{ 
    $containers[] = $row[container_name];
    $containerid[] = $row[container_id];

}
```

to

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{ 
    $containers[] = $row['container_name'];
    $containerid[] = $row['container_id'];

}
```

you missed `'`.

Comment: Ok, changed it. Still got the same problem :(

Answer (score 0):

$count is in essence only a single value (as you are counting a single container), so it will work for the first element, but not for subsequent elements. Quick fix is to use mysql_result:

```
$count = mysql_result($result, 0);
```

as ever, this code is using mysql functions that are both insecure and due to be deprecated - do consider switching to mysqli or pdo.

Answer (score 0):

> Am I doing something stupid here?

Yes.

Splitting the same data across multiple tables is really dumb.

```
$sql = "select * from containers";
...
while ($v1 < 14)
{
   ...
   $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `$containername` WHERE state = 'Empty';";
```

Relational database management systems are very good at performing joins. Procedural / OO languages are NOT.

If all your containerX tables where in a single table then the performance would be a lot better and the code much simpler. And it's trivial to create views named like the individual tables on an aggregated table thus avoiding having to rewrite most of your code straight away.

Why are you fetching all the containers then only processing the first 14?

What is $v2 doing?

It's rather hard to work out why your code is misbehaving as your description doesn't match your code - your query states "WHERE state = 'Empty'" but your table description has no column named state (and if that were an accurate report, then the code would stop on the first iteration with a MySQL error message).